# Read access violation when calling size_t *size as *z

Tags: c, casting

Usually, I write a long piece of text, but this problem is rather simple. I'm currently working on some Python C API stuff, and need to parse a python integer to a `size_t*` type. If no integer is given, I want the size to default to `sizeof(int)` but get an error. The following minimal example shows my issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    size_t *size = (size_t*)sizeof(int);
    fprintf(stdout, "size is: %zu\n", *size);
}
```

Could someone explain to me what is going on here other than "Read access violation error"?

Comment: Could you explain what you are attempting to do with `size_t *size = (size_t*)sizeof(int);`?

Comment: Why is `size` a pointer to a `size_t`?

Comment: Basic undefined behavior? dereferencing a random pointer.

Comment: Did you mean `size_t size = sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: This is C, not C++

Comment: *"Could someone explain to me what is going on here"* - yeah, the author has no idea what they're doing, and is relegated to cooking spaghetti (throw something at the wall and see if it sticks). Harsh reality, yes, but true regardless. A good book is on the menu. And fyi, if you removed *every* asterisk in this code (and with that, the cast against `sizeof(int)`) it would make considerably more sense.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I want to call a function `SetTagsize(size_t *size)`, which sets the size of a message that's being sent between threads. I'm trying to set this message size equal to the size of an `int`, but the line `const uint32_t newSize = (uint32_t) * size;` within this function throws this error. The minimum example above is the furthest I could reduce it down. I know the problem lies in the pointer, but the function `SetTagsize(size_t *size)` is immutable, so I'm stuck with that type.

Comment: @MitchellFaas The function almost certainly wants a pointer to a `size_t` that contains the size. You would want to store the size in a `size_t` and give it's address to your function. For example : `size_t my_size = sizeof(int); SetTagSize(&my_size);`

Comment: @WhozCraig Instead of chastising based on limited information and uninformed assumptions, you could perhaps opt to contribute something productive or nothing at all? If I knew what I was doing, I wouldn't have to ask any questions, so I'll grant you that point flat out. That said, I'm aware that the pointers are creating the issue, but don't know how to fix the issue while retaining the pointer (which is exactly what I need). Sometimes when doing research you run in to issues which don't seem to make a lot of sense. Im under the impression that questions are asked when you're confused.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This makes a lot of sense; I can't believe we didn't think of that before... You're a life saver!

Comment: @MitchellFaas If your content put in comment *after* mine describing the `SetTagSize(size_t *)` api were part of the actual question, things would have likely gone smoother. If it sounded terse, so be it, but knowing that key piece of information from the outset would have made your code hurdle crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

> what is going on here other than "Read access violation error"?

my guess :

```
size_t *size = (size_t*)sizeof(int);
                        ^^^^^^ 1
                        ------^^^^^ 2
               ^^^^^^^^^ 3

// 1) sizeof() returns byte count in an unsigned integral type
// 2) sizeof(int) is 4 or 8 depending on compiler and target system

// For diagnostic, I added: 
fprintf(stdout, "\n  lu int size: %lu\n", sizeof(int)); 
// on my lubuntu 18.04 desktop, this line reports: "  lu int size: 4"

// 3) (size_t*) is a c-style cast of the value of sizeof(int)
// fprintf(stdout, "\n  size is: %zu\n", *size);

// g++ reports format ‘%zu’ expects argument of type ‘size_t’
// 
// Running your printf on my lubuntu gives a "3403 Segmentation fault"
// with core dump.
```

---

Summary: I think "what is going on" is that you are attempting to access 
address 0x00000008 in your system, which is apparently not allowed.

Does your system (compiler / os / hw) allow access to address 0x00000008 ?  Many embedded systems do not.

Is this really something you want to do? (i.e. read an int from an address (maybe 0x00000008) derived from the sizeof an int)

---

Experiment:

You might try to read that address using some other technique ...  int? byte? char? access

---

Possible root cause:

Perhaps your OS requires special privileges for the accessing processes / task.

Perhaps your HW has no memory at that location